# Cannot create schema : permission issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a schema.

But I am getting this error :

```
mysql> create schema myBase;
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './myBase' (Errcode: 13 -
Permission denied)
```

When I do a ls -l on /var/lib I am getting :

```
drw-rw-rw- 8 mysql         mysql         4096 juin   6 14:41 mysql
```

I don't know what is wrong here.
I anyone knows..

Comment: 13 means OS permissions issue and it seem execute permission is missing. what are the permissions at datadir level? as create schema would create directory so make sure mysql process user at os can create directories at OS

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have execute otherwise you cannot "CD" into the directory nor MySQL will be able to.

Run this to fix directories recursively:

```
for dir in $(find /var/lib/mysql -type d); do chmod u+x $dir; done
```